# Phone and Twitter Authentication for Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

Can somebody please provide me link for complete projects which has used Twitter Authentication and phone Authentication for Firebase? I went through the firebase documents, but didn't understood it. For Twitter, I don't want the implementation using Fabric as Google now owns Fabric they have different implementation. I searched a lot through Google, but most of the sites have copy pasted the documents of Authentication From Firebase. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is The Sample Project Which Uses All type of Authentication Methods.
It is made by Google. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android

Comment: I hope that this does helps you ...  Reply me if this really helped you.

Comment: There Will Be Folder Named auth inside it. The Sample Contains Every Feature Of Firebase.

Comment: Got it. Not tried it yet.Will let you know if it works or not.